# Codeigniter select_avg('columnname') WHERE thisaverage > x

Tags: codeigniter, activerecord, average

What I want to do is select items from my database where the average review is greater than 7.

```
$this->db->select_avg('reviews.overall');
```

That query selects the average review 'as overall'.

Therefore i assumed i could simply then use

```
$this->db->where('overall>','7');
```

This however does not work.

ANy ideas?

Thanks

EDIT
Putting in a space

```
        $this->db->select_avg('reviews.overall');
    $this->db->where('overall >','7');
```

Yields the error

> Column 'overall' in where clause is ambiguous

It is ambiguous but how am I now meant to reference it??

Thx

Comment: Did you try adding a space between the `overall` and `>`?

Comment: Does `$this->db->where('reviews.overall >','7');` work?

Comment: But what is overall in your query? A table too?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's writen in the codeigniter user manual too:

`$this->db->select_avg();` Writes a "SELECT AVG(field)" portion for your query. As with select_max(), You can optionally include a second parameter to rename the resulting field.

If you enable profiler in CI, you would see, what query does this code generate.
Your code is generated like this:

```
SELECT AVG(reviews.overall) as reviews.overall FROM ....
```

Use it like this:

```
$this->db->select_avg('reviews','overall');
$this->db->from('table name');
$this->db->where('overal >', 7);
$Q = $this->db->get();
```

Comment: Thanks. Apologies for the confusion but i've referenced it as 'reviews.overall' as I am joining two tables within the query..

Comment: This code not working. I am using $this->db->select_avg('rating','overall')->from('cursor_rating')->where('overall >',5)->get(); It show me Error Number: 1054

Unknown column 'overall' in 'where clause'

SELECT AVG(`rating`) AS `overall` FROM `cursor_rating` WHERE `overall` > 5